# is there any specific generator i need to install so that devise can work in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to add the device gem in my rails app so I added

`gem 'devise'` to my gem file and i ran

`bundle install`

but when i'm trying to run

`rails generate devise:install`

I'm getting this error:

```
Could not find generator 'devise:install'. Maybe you meant 'assets', 'generator' or 'coffee:assets'
```

what should i do to make it install?

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec rails generate devise:install`, or somehow `spring stop; rails generate devise install`?

Comment: yes I tried that but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to add gem is going to https://rubygems.org and search specify gem
for your situation you should add `gem 'devise', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.1'` to your Gemfile, then go back to console type `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

is it maybe just error you wrote "bunBle install",  you should use '`bundle install`' also check result after you run this command if everything is okay and run this command to be sure devise is installed '`gem list --local devise`'